# Jquery - Search in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I'm trying to search a `<ul>`

Basically as I'm writing it needs to hide/show the `<li>` elements that correspond.

**HTML**

```
<input id="searchUtil" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisa..."/>

<ul id="ulutilizadores" class="list-group">
   <li>**some code*</li>
</ul>
```

As of now I have this:

```
//#searchUtil is the <input> id
$('#searchUtil').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var searchText = $(this).val();


//#ulutilizadores is the <ul> id
    $('#ulutilizadores li').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text.indexOf(searchText)) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

This isn't working.
I've been searching but I don't really find some good answers. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you post the html, a jsfiddle will be better.

Comment: whats is #searchUtil
What is #ulutilizadores .. Without HTML its difficult to help u

Comment: I've added what they are.

Comment: just paste the html instead please

Comment: What is not working it should be

Comment: Oh, I know: `var text = $(this).text();`. `.val()` is for inputs

Comment: duhh. I feeld stupid now xD Thank @DOC ASAREL it works now

Comment: You can throw an answer down below so i can accept it.

Comment: And you can use:  var $this = $(this); text = $this.text();
And other places like : $this.hide() .... $this.show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a slight error in your code

```
var text = $(this).val();
```

should be

```
var text = $(this).text();
```

in your case.

> [*The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.*](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
>   jQuery manual

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. In this you search on exact the same text. Change to searchText.Contains(this.innerHTML) or something like that to get where the text contains in the list.

HTML:

```
<ul id="ulutilizadores" class="list-group">
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test1</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#searchUtil').change(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val();
     $('#ulutilizadores li').each(function () {
        if(searchText !== this.innerHTML )
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
         else
         {
             $(this).show();
         }
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sow61xe4/)